# Recycler View With Grid layout Manager and item decorator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I have the below XML from URL and want the below layout with the values filled with the XML data I am getting from URL.

**Below is the xml from url**

```
 <Seat>
<ColumnNo>0</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>2</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>E</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>1</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>SL5</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>2</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel/> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>3</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>SL1</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>4</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>SL2</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>5</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>2</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>A</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>6</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>2</Deck> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>B</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>2</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<RowNo>1</RowNo>
<SeatLabel/> 
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>0</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>2</Deck> 
<RowNo>2</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>F</SeatLabel> 
</Seat>
```

with the below code

**A.java**

```
 public class A extends Activity {
          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MarginDecoration(this));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 6));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new NumberedAdapter(18));


          }
        }
```

**MarginDecoration.java**

```
public class MarginDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
  private int margin;

  public MarginDecoration(Context context) {
    margin = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_margin);
  }

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets(
      Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.set(margin, margin, margin, margin);
  }
}
```

**activity_recycler_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/item_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

The all above i did with the help of this [Github link](https://github.com/chiuki/android-recyclerview/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sqisland/android/recyclerview)

Comment: What is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- [Aquire the XML](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Parse it](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)
- [Set up an adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

You can find several [tutorials](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/recyclerview-json-parsing.html) looking for something like "recyclerview tutorial", "xml parsing android" and "android network libraries".